# Как преобразовать массив в фрейм данных?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, datetime, обработка-данных

Как преобразовать массив в фейм данных, где первый столбце - время, а второй - `df['numbers']`?

```
[[1619247540000, 5028],
 [1619247600000, 5029],
 [1619247660000, 5011],
 [1619247720000, 5005],
 [1619247780000, 5003]
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

пример:

```
In [41]: data = [[1619247540000, 5028],
    ...:  [1619247600000, 5029],
    ...:  [1619247660000, 5011],
    ...:  [1619247720000, 5005],
    ...:  [1619247780000, 5003]]

In [42]: df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=["Date", "Number"])

In [43]: df
Out[43]:
            Date  Number
0  1619247540000    5028
1  1619247600000    5029
2  1619247660000    5011
3  1619247720000    5005
4  1619247780000    5003
```

Если захотите перевести `UNIX timestamp` в `datetime`:

```
In [44]: df["Date"] = pd.to_datetime(df["Date"], unit="ms")

In [45]: df
Out[45]:
                 Date  Number
0 2021-04-24 06:59:00    5028
1 2021-04-24 07:00:00    5029
2 2021-04-24 07:01:00    5011
3 2021-04-24 07:02:00    5005
4 2021-04-24 07:03:00    5003
```

---

> А можете добавить еще разбиение даты на Дату и Время?

В Pandas/Numpy нет такого типа данных как время (без даты), поэтому можно преобразовать только в строку, но никакие арифметические операции с этим столбцом производить нельзя:

```
In [46]: df["Time"] = df["Date"].dt.strftime("%H:%M:%S")

In [47]: df["Date"] = df["Date"].dt.floor("D")

In [48]: df
Out[48]:
        Date  Number      Time
0 2021-04-24    5028  06:59:00
1 2021-04-24    5029  07:00:00
2 2021-04-24    5011  07:01:00
3 2021-04-24    5005  07:02:00
4 2021-04-24    5003  07:03:00
```

---

Если впоследствии нужно будет делать какие то операции со столбцом `Time` тогда можно его преобразовать к типу `Timedelta`:

```
In [50]: df["Delta"] = pd.to_timedelta(df["Time"])

In [51]: df
Out[51]:
        Date  Number      Time           Delta
0 2021-04-24    5028  06:59:00 0 days 06:59:00
1 2021-04-24    5029  07:00:00 0 days 07:00:00
2 2021-04-24    5011  07:01:00 0 days 07:01:00
3 2021-04-24    5005  07:02:00 0 days 07:02:00
4 2021-04-24    5003  07:03:00 0 days 07:03:00

In [52]: df["Date"] + df["Delta"]
Out[52]:
0   2021-04-24 06:59:00
1   2021-04-24 07:00:00
2   2021-04-24 07:01:00
3   2021-04-24 07:02:00
4   2021-04-24 07:03:00
dtype: datetime64[ns]
```